# What normal variational vector fields are allowed for the area to be preserved?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curvature, minimal-surfaces

Let $(M^3,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with boundary and let $\varphi : \Sigma \to M$ be a two-sided proper embedding of a compact surface with boundary, with unit normal $N$.

If $\varphi$ is not minimal (the mean curvature $H$ is not identically zero), then for every $f \in C^\infty(\Sigma)$ such that $\int_\Sigma f H \, \mathrm{d} vol_{\varphi^\ast g} = 0$ there exists a proper variation $\varphi_t$ of $\varphi$ such that

(a) $\operatorname{Area}(\Sigma, \varphi_t^\ast g) = \operatorname{Area}(\Sigma, \varphi^\ast g)$ for every $t$; and

(b) $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \varphi_t \vert_{t=0} = fN$.

What are the "permitted" $f$ when $\varphi$ is minimal? To be more precise, let $\mathcal{F} \subset C^\infty(\Sigma)$ be the subspace of all $f$ such that there exists a variation $\varphi_t$ of $\varphi$ satisfying conditions (a) and (b) above. Can we "describe" $\mathcal{F}$ in general? For instance, is this subspace finite or infinite dimensional?

Comment: The infinitesimal version of your question is basically about the spectrum of the stability operator of the minimal surface. In the case where you have a strictly stable minimal surface, it would be an actual area minimizer and so the subspace contains only the "0" function. When the minimal surface is unstable, there is at least one negative eigenvalue and _infinitely many_ positive eigenvalues, so at least for the infinitesimal question the subspace should be infinite dimensional.

Comment: Finally when the minimal surface is area minimizing but the stability operator has a non-trivial kernel, this kernel should be finite dimensional by Fredholm, and infinitesimally there may be a finite dimensional $\mathcal{F}$. // The keyword you want to look for is "Morse index of minimal surface". // You may also want to ping Otis Chodosh (he is frequently on MO) since he would know the literature better than I do about this.